# Rails hamlit LoadError. Incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After installing many gems sucessfully, I'm facing a LoadError problem when I call rails local server (with rails s).
The complaining is related to incompatible library version.

```
gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit/attribute_builder.rb:2:in `require': incompatible library version - /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit/hamlit.so (LoadError)
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit/attribute_builder.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit/attribute_compiler.rb:2:in `require'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit/attribute_compiler.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit/compiler/tag_compiler.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit/compiler/tag_compiler.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit/compiler.rb:7:in `require'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit/compiler.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit/engine.rb:4:in `require'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit/engine.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit.rb:2:in `require'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/hamlit-2.8.1/lib/hamlit.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
from /usr/local/RubyWorkspace/produtos_adaptativos/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/RubyWorkspace/produtos_adaptativos/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /usr/local/RubyWorkspace/produtos_adaptativos/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/spring-2.0.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /usr/local/RubyWorkspace/produtos_adaptativos/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Do I need to do a downgrade of this lib?

Answer (score 0):

You can run these commands:

```
gem uninstall hamlit
bundle install
```

References: http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-pristine [Ruby on Rails incompatible library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474847/ruby-on-rails-incompatible-library)