# Cannot run migrations on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I believe I have an environment setup issue here, which I cannot seem to figure out. Trying to generate a migration in order to set up my Users table, but keep receiving the following message.

`gem pristine --all`

```
Sunnys-MBP:Vine SunnyPatel$ rails generate migration Users
/Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/Desktop/Vine/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/Desktop/Vine/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/Desktop/Vine/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/Desktop/Vine/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
from /Users/SunnyPatel/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474847/ruby-on-rails-incompatible-library take a look at this accepted answer. As error starts with msgpack, maybe msgpack reinstall can fix this error

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the fact that the system version of ruby is different to the version for your application.

Try appending `bundle exec` to your command.

```rb
bundle exec rails generate migration Users
```

Also, it's not likely that your command will work. You want to create a new User model? Then you want this command instead:

```rb
bundle exec rails generate model User
```